# UPDATE COLUMN value with business logic applied

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have data as follows

```
id name rank     
1   X     1       
2   Q     1         
2   T     2          
1   R     2          
1   E     3
```

I have business logic which needs to put weight for id column as follows:

```
id  name  rank  weight  
1   X     1      33  
2   Q     1      50  
2   T     2      50  
1   R     2      33  
1   E     3      34
```

100 has to be divided among all records with same ids.

There are two records where id=2 so weight =`50+50`.
There are three records where id=1 so weight=`33+33+34`.
Similarly if id's count=4 the weight would be `25+25+25+25`
if id's count=6 the weight would be `16+16+17+17+17+17`
if id count=7 the weight would be `14+14+14+14+14+15+15`

I require to implement this logic in SQL or PL/SQL.

The dataset conatins millions of rows so I require a generic algorithm.

Comment: Can you show us what you have coded so far, and where specifically in the code that you have written already you are having trouble?

Comment: OP wants to distribute integral weights evenly across a group of rows with the same id. They need to be adjusted so the total is 100.

Comment: i tried implementing by cursor but was unable to get desired result :(

Answer (score 2):

As pseudo-code I think you want something like this. `Divisor` is going to be a count of all the items with the same id. Be careful to make sure you aren't doing integer divisions while you're working through this problem.

```
set weight = case
    when rank <= divisor - (100 - trunc(100e0 / divisor) * divisor)
    then trunc(100e0 / divisor)
    else trunc(100e0 / divisor) + 1
end
```

Here's a fiddle as a proof of concept. It doesn't do the update though. Note that I changed the column `rank` to `rnk` because I wasn't sure if that was a reserved word on Oracle.

```
with T as (
    select id, rnk, count(*) over (partition by id) as divisor
    from <your_table>
)
select id, rnk,
    case
        when rnk <= divisor - (100 - trunc(100e0 / divisor) * divisor)
        then trunc(100e0 / divisor)
        else trunc(100e0 / divisor) + 1  
    end as weight
from T
order by id, rnk;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ecdad/7

My original impression of your question was that you needed an `update` but now after re-reading I'm not sure about that. Perhaps this works? I see other people on the internet claiming that (some) CTEs are updatable on (some) versions of Oracle.

```
with T as (
    select *, count(*) over (partition by id) as divisor from <your_table>
)
update T
set weight = case
    when rank <= divisor - (100 - trunc(100e0 / divisor) * divisor)
    then trunc(100e0 / divisor)
    else trunc(100e0 / divisor) + 1
end
```

I made some attempts but couldn't get an `update` to work with a CTE but this uglier version was fine:

```
update <your_table>
set weight = case
    when rank <=
        (select count(*) from <your_table> t2 where t2.id = <your_table>.id)
         - (100
             - trunc(
               100e0 /
               (select count(*) from <your_table> t2 where t2.id = <your_table>.id)
             )
             * (select count(*) from <your_table> t2 where t2.id = <your_table>.id)
           )
    then trunc(100e0
           / (select count(*) from <your_table> t2 where t2.id = <your_table>.id))
    else trunc(100e0
           / (select count(*) from <your_table> t2 where t2.id = <your_table>.id)) + 1  
end;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ecdad/18

Following Matthew's example of using `merge` you would have this form for an update that should work with the CTE:

```
merge into <yourtable> tgt
using (
    with T as (
        select id, rnk, count(*) over (partition by id) as divisor
        from <your_table>
    )
    select id, rnk,
        case
            when rnk <= divisor - (100 - trunc(100e0 / divisor) * divisor)
            then trunc(100e0 / divisor)
            else trunc(100e0 / divisor) + 1  
        end as weight
    from T
) src
on (tgt.rowid = src.rowid) /* or: tgt.id = src.id and tgt.rank = src.rank */
when matched then
    update set weight = src.weight
```

Comment: I think a merge with analytics would be faster for "millions of records" than an update with a nested `SELECT COUNT(*)` for each row.

Comment: I agree (although this is a simple subquery). Oracle isn't my specialty: Do you know how to get the update to work with a table expression and the analytic count?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need PL/SQL.

This is the `SELECT` statement that will compute the `weight` column as you need.  To get the results into your table, you can just wrap this in a `MERGE`.

The basic idea is to compute the raw weight as `100/count(*)` and round off fractional values. Then, add those all up within each `id` and see how much below 100 you are.  If, say, the total of rounded-off values is 96, you are 4 off, so you need to add 1 to the first 4 rows in each id.

```
WITH test_data AS ( 
      SELECT 1 ID, dbms_random.string('U',1) name, rownum rank FROM DUAL connect by rownum <= 6
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 ID, dbms_random.string('U',1) name, rownum rank FROM DUAL connect by rownum <= 3
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 ID, dbms_random.string('U',1) name, rownum rank FROM DUAL connect by rownum <= 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 ID, dbms_random.string('U',1) name, rownum rank FROM DUAL connect by rownum <= 27
     ),
     pass1 AS
       (SELECT d.*,
               100 / COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY d.id) raw_rank,
               FLOOR (100 / COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY d.id)) raw_rank_floor,
               ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY d.id ORDER BY d.RANK) rank_in_id
        FROM   test_data d),
     pass2 AS
       (SELECT p1.*,
               100 - SUM (raw_rank_floor) OVER (PARTITION BY p1.id) adds_needed
        FROM   pass1 p1)
SELECT p2.id,
       p2.name,
       p2.RANK,
       p2.raw_rank_floor + CASE WHEN p2.rank_in_id <= p2.adds_needed THEN 1 ELSE 0 END weight
FROM   pass2 p2
ORDER BY p2.id, p2.RANK;
order by p2.id, p2.rank;
```

### To accomplish the update

To apply the above concept to an update, just wrap it in a `MERGE` statement.  Here is a complete example.  This this example `matt_target` is a replacement for whatever your table is named.

```
DROP TABLE matt_target;

CREATE TABLE matt_target ( id number, name varchar2(1), rank number, weight number(3,0) );

INSERT INTO matt_target (id, name, rank ) (
      SELECT 1 ID, dbms_random.string('U',1) name, rownum rank FROM DUAL connect by rownum <= 6
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 ID, dbms_random.string('U',1) name, rownum rank FROM DUAL connect by rownum <= 3
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 ID, dbms_random.string('U',1) name, rownum rank FROM DUAL connect by rownum <= 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 ID, dbms_random.string('U',1) name, rownum rank FROM DUAL connect by rownum <= 27
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 ID, dbms_random.string('U',1) name, rownum rank FROM DUAL connect by rownum <= 300     );

COMMIT;      

-- This is your answer right here.  Do this.
MERGE INTO matt_target t
USING (
WITH pass1 AS
       (SELECT d.rowid row_id, 
               d.*,
               100 / COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY d.id) raw_rank,
               FLOOR (100 / COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY d.id)) raw_rank_floor,
               ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY d.id ORDER BY d.RANK) rank_in_id
        FROM   matt_target d),
     pass2 AS
       (SELECT p1.*,
               100 - SUM (raw_rank_floor) OVER (PARTITION BY p1.id) adds_needed
        FROM   pass1 p1)
SELECT p2.row_id,
       p2.id,
       p2.name,
       p2.RANK,
       p2.raw_rank_floor + CASE WHEN p2.rank_in_id <= p2.adds_needed THEN 1 ELSE 0 END weight
FROM   pass2 p2
ORDER BY p2.id, p2.RANK ) u
ON ( t.rowid = u.row_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.weight = u.weight;

-- Check the results.
SELECT * FROM matt_target;
```

Comment: The dataset are in millions , i just displayed for just 3 ids, i need a generic algorithm

Comment: Did you read my answer?  This will work for as many rows as you want.  The `test_data` part is just to make the answer self-contained.  You'd replace that with your actual table.